# Output prediction cannot understand the while statement

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, output

I'm looking for the expalanation of this problem. I cannot understand the while part and why does it print 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = {1, 2, 4, 0, 4, 0, 3};
    int *p, sum = 0;

    p = &array[0];

    while (*p++)
        sum += *p;

    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any `non-zero` number is `true` condition. Thus your loop runs till first `0`.

Comment: For your own sake (and ours too) please invest a minute or two of your time and format your code

Comment: the root cause of the problem is the ignoring of the C operator precedence, where the `++` will be performed, then the dereference

Answer (score 5):

This is a more readable form of your while loop:

```
while (*p != 0)
{
  p = p + 1;   // you can put "p++;" here, which has the same effect
  sum += *p;
}
```

Now you should understand on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Initially the pointer `p` points to the first element of the array.

```
p = &array[0];
```

However after evaluation the condition of the while statement

```
while(*p++)
```

the pointer was incremented and after that it points to the second element of the array that is to `2`.

Within the body of the loop there is used the incremented pointer.

So you will have

```
2 + 4
```

The forth element of the array is equal to `0`. So the loop stops its iterations.

You can consider the condition in the while loop the following way if to rewrite it as a for loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
     int array[] = {1,2,4,0,4,0,3};
    int *p, sum=0;
    p = &array[0];

    for ( int *tmp = p; ( ++p, *tmp != 0 ); tmp = p )
    {
        sum += *p;
    }

    printf("%d\n",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

If within the body to use the statement

```
sum += *tmp;
```

instead of

```
sum += *p;
```

then you will get the expected result equal to `7`.

Answer (score 1):

you are discarding the value from first element of array.

that is the reason why you see answer 6

you sum elements *after* you already moved to the next element of array

you should increment pointer in the end of iteration

```
while(*p){
  sum += *p;
  p++;
}
```

or

```
for( ; *p ; p++){
  sum += *p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs until it encounters a zero value. However you increment your pointer before adding what it points to, to "sum".

So the loop adds the second and third elements to sum and stops at the fourth.

The value of sum is then: 0 + 2 + 4 = 6

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your `while` loop as

```
while(*p)
sum += *p++;
```

**Explanation**

`++, ––` are unary operators used to increment, decrement the value of a variable by 1.

They can be used as `postfix` or `prefix`

But this was not just your problem. While loop terminated when it receives `0`. Your array contains one of it.

So, instead use

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)  //7 -> size of array
sum += *p++;
```

o/p - `14`